# View with drawable background doesn't show on layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview

I'm trying to create a blue background for a row in a listView, but the background only appears in the XML preview and not when I run the app.

The row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/row_background"
        android:id="@+id/mBackground" />

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

The background layout:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:thicknessRatio="9"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

All the other views are showing normally, I tried different ways to draw reacts in the background file but non of them worked.
Can someone help me please.

Comment: Try with a fixed width in your view( instead of *wrap_content*).

Comment: change wrap_content to match_parent

Comment: provide View height fixed size (eq. android:layout_height="20dp")